# Why is a homotopy limit of a cosimplicial space not the ordinary limit?

Tags: at.algebraic-topology, model-categories, homotopy-limits

I've been trying to compute a homotopy limit of a cosimplicial object $X: \Delta \to \mathscr{M}$, where $\mathscr{M}$ is some simplicial model category, we may take it to be spaces. I'm wondering where I go wrong with the following argument.

Let $X'$ be a fibrant replacement of $X$ in the Reedy model category $\mathscr{M}^{\Delta}$. Then we have maps $X \to X' \to *$, where the first map is a trivial cofibration and the second a fibration. In particular, the maximal augmentations of $X,X'$ are isomorphic by (Hirschhorn, *Model Categories and their localizations*, Thm. 15.9.9).

Let $T$ be the category $[0] \rightrightarrows [1]$. Then these maximal augmentations are nothing more than the limit on $T$, and $T$ includes finally into $\Delta$.  Hence we would have
\begin{align}
\mathrm{holim}_{n \in \Delta} X \simeq \lim_{n\in \Delta} X' \cong \lim_{n \in T} X' \cong \lim_{n \in T} X \cong \lim_{n \in \Delta} X
\end{align}

The conclusion doesn't seem right to me. Could anybody point out where I went wrong?

Comment: I found a hint to the answer in *The Theory and Practice of Reedy Categories* (Riehl, Verity), Exmpl. 8.10. Apparently, the constant diagram functor $\mathscr{M} \to \mathscr{M}^{\Delta}$ is not left Quillen. I guess that in this case one cannot compute the homotopy limit as a limit on a fibrant replacement. I'd still like a confirmation of this :)

Comment: I do not understand why $\lim_T X'\cong \lim_T X$ in your last equation. Indeed I'd expect it not to be the case

Comment: So $\lim_T X \cong \lim_T X'$ follows from the fact that $X \to X'$ is a cofibration, which means that their maximal augmentations are isomorphic. The way I understand it, these limits are precisely that. 

I think the problem is that in this case the homotopy limit cannot be computed as the limit of the Reedy fibrant replacement.